# how to store request parameter in a variable and used it another request

Tags: postman

my request is:
{
"username": "test"
}
i want store this request in a variable and again called this in another request., I tried it for response part, but not sure how to achieve it for request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

**Request 1:**

I assume you have body like this

```
{
    "username": "test"
}
```

`Tests` tab: Save a part of body in a variable

```
const body = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);
pm.environment.set("username", body.username);
```

**Request 2:**

`Body` tab: Use this var as a normal variable.

```
{
    "username": "{{username}}",
    "pass": "11111"
}
```

Comment: Potentially, might need to `JSON.stringify()` the body?

Comment: Partially correct, in my 1st request i have many parameter as well, i dont want to use all of them in my 2nd request, only the value "username" want to re-use. currently it taking all the request and replace in another api request.

Comment: @DannyDainton I've tested this before, its type is `string`, not `object`

Comment: @prem I've updated my answer to fit your situation.